# Kotlinx date time how to get last year?

Tags: kotlin, timezone, java-time, kotlinx-datetime

I'm using Kotlinx.dateTime. And I need to get the current date and the current date - 12 months.

Here is my code for current date:

```
val currentDate: LocalDateTime = Clock.System.now()
        .toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault())
```

But I can't understand how to retrieve current date - 12 months. Because as far as I can see kotlin.time.Duration does not contain Duration.Months, only NANOSECONDS, MICROSECONDS, MILLISECONDS, SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS.
So I can't write something like this:

```
val lastYear: LocalDateTime = Clock.System.now().minus(12.months).toLocalDateTime(
        TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()
```

Please help me.

Comment: This is because once you go past days, timezones start to matter. So you'll need to convert to something timezone-aware, such as `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: if you dont need the Time part then `currentDate.date.minus(DatePeriod(months = 12))`